# Printing to a txt file in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

Hi i'm new to ARM assembly, I was just curious to know what I'm doing wrong. I want to print an Integer to another txt file. The code I have is below, but I just keep getting a blank file. I was able to read an Integer from a txt file and I have it stored in r6 (PS I just took out the parts of my code that seemed relevant to my question).

```
  .equ SWI_Open, 0x66 
  .equ SWI_Close,0x68  
  .equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b 
  .equ SWI_RdInt,0x6c 
  .equ SWI_PrStr,0x69 
  .equ Stdout, 1 
  .equ SWI_Exit, 0x11    

   ldr r0,=OutFile 
   mov r1,#0 
   swi SWI_Open                    
   ldr r1,=InputFileHandle
   str r0,[r1]
   ldr r6,=Number
   ldr r0,=InputFileHandle 
   ldr r1, [r6]
   swi SWI_PrInt

.data
OutFile: .asciz "out.txt"
.align
Number: .skip 1024
InputFileHandle: .skip 4
```

Comment: Which OS is this for?

Comment: Sorry if I don't answer correctly but I'm using windows 8..If it helps I'm using arm sim.

Comment: In mean the (simulated) OS the ARM code is going to run on.

Comment: We need to know what the calling conventions of the SWI call `SWI_PrInt` are, and what it actually does to be able to help.

Comment: In other words, what do you expect to be on the other end of the `swi`?

Comment: I added all of the swi I use in my program to help. I also use this http://armsim.cs.uvic.ca/AttachedFiles/ARMSim_UserGuide4Plus.pdf pg. 21 has most of the swi instructions in ARM sim